# Errors using OCI: "expects parameter 1 to be resource"

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

I'm getting the following errors when trying to access a database using OCI:

> oci_parse() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   oci_bind_by_name() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   oci_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,

The connection is ok, I checked it.

This is my code:

```
//<?php


class Connecter
{
    protected $tns = null;


    protected $account = 'acc';
    protected $password = 'pass';

    public $conn;  

    public function __construct()
    {
        $tns = " 
          (DESCRIPTION =
              (ADDRESS_LIST =  
                (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
              )
              (CONNECT_DATA =
                (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
              )
          )";        
        $this -> conn = oci_connect("acc", "pass", $tns);
        return $this->conn;
    }

} //


/*<?php
include "domains/Connecter.php";

$con = new Connecter();
$query    = 'SELECT BLOBDATA FROM BTAB WHERE BLOBID = :MYBLOBID';
$stmt     = oci_parse($con, $query);
$myblobid = 1;
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':MYBLOBID', $myblobid);
oci_execute($stmt);
$arr    = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_ASSOC);
$result = $arr['BLOBDATA']->load();

header("Content-type: image/JPEG");
echo $result;

oci_close($con);

?>
*/
```

Comment: It  looks like the end of your error message was cut off.

Answer (score 0):

`new Connecter()` will return a PHP object, not a resource, which is what `oci_parse()` is expecting.

You haven't posted `Connecter.php` so it's not possible to say exactly what needs to change, but somewhere in there you're establishing a connection. You need to find a way to get the returned value out of your class so you can use it. Since you're not using an OOP structure for the rest of the code, perhaps you should just abandon the `Connecter` class and use a procedural approach throughout.

Side note: *connector* is spelt with an *o*

Comment: //<?php


class Connecter
{
    protected $tns = null;
    
    
    protected $account = 'acc';
    protected $password = 'pass';
    
    public $conn;  
  
    public function __construct()
    {
        $tns = " 
          (DESCRIPTION =
              (ADDRESS_LIST =  
                (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
              )
              (CONNECT_DATA =
                (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
              )
          )";        
        $this -> conn = oci_connect("acc", "pass", $tns);
        return $this->conn;
    }
    
} //

Comment: So based on this answer and your connector having the `oci_connect` on `$this->conn`, sounds like you should be using `oci_parse($con->conn, $query);` Right?

Comment: Also, it might be a bit more appropriate to have a method on the actual `Connector` class like `parse` that accepts a query string as an argument and actually calls `oci_parse($this->conn, $query)` instead of only having the `Connector` just for creating the resource.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in Hobo's answer, `oci_parse` requires the first argument to be a resource, whereas you are passing it the `Connector` object containing the resource. So the simple fix would be to change your code to:

```
$con = new Connecter();
$query    = 'SELECT BLOBDATA FROM BTAB WHERE BLOBID = :MYBLOBID';
$stmt     = oci_parse($con->conn, $query);
```

It would probably bit more appropriate, however, to build out your `Connector` class and make it more of an OCI8 DB handling class to hold most or all of the oci8 functions, such as `oci_parse`. Consider something like:

```
protected function parse($query) {

      $response = oci_parse($this->conn, $query);
      return $response;
}

/* end of new method bit */

$con = new Connecter();
$query    = 'SELECT BLOBDATA FROM BTAB WHERE BLOBID = :MYBLOBID';
$stmt     = $conn->parse($query);
```